# Regex Not Finding All Matches C#

Tags: c#, regex

I researched, tested and used RegEx.101 and could not figure this out.  I spent hours on it.

I am looking for **16** *digit numbers*.

Here is my regular expression:   `"[0-9]{16}"`

Here is the code:

```
Regex ItemRegex = new Regex("[0-9]{16}");
// test with a 29 digit number
foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches("564654564553314342340968580654"))
{
    i++;
}
```

I am expecting multiple matches but I am only getting the first 16 digits.  How do I get the first 16 digits starting at position one, then the second 16 digits starting at position 2, then the third, etc?

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated and +1'd.

Comment: This `(?=(\d{16}))`?

Comment: Your regulat expression is ok, but how do you expect to have two 16 char strings from 30 characters? Add more numbers to your string

Comment: I would like many matches!  the first 16 digits starting with the first number, the 16 digits starting with the second number, etc.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky: a 29 digit number contains 14 substrings of 16 digit numbers.

Comment: @ctwheels is correct

Comment: if @ctwheels is correct then they should really post it as an answer. That way it could be upvoted and accepted and all those sorts of things. :)

Comment: Chris is correct :)  -- @ctwheels should post it as an answer!   It worked!  Yay!!!   Now if only ItemMatch worked properly....   I figured out a workaround so it's all good :)

Comment: Are there people who spend hours hunting for duplicates then downvote them?  Seriously, Wiktor.  I really tried to find an answer before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/o4GslN/1)

```
(?=(\d{16}))
```

- `(?=(\d{16}))` Positive lookahead ensuring the following follows the current position

  - `(\d{16})` Capture 16 digits into capture group 1

Result:

```
5646545645533143
6465456455331434
4654564553314342
6545645533143423
5456455331434234
4564553314342340
5645533143423409
6455331434234096
4553314342340968
5533143423409685
5331434234096858
3314342340968580
3143423409685806
1434234096858065
4342340968580654
```

So how does this work? Well, a lookahead `(?=)` is a zero-width assertion that checks whether or not the subpattern it contains matches at that specific location in the string. Since we haven't anchored our regex, this will attempt to match every *position* in the string.

So what does it mean to be a zero-width assertion? A lookaround actually matches characters and then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. In our case, we've also added a capturing group to the positive lookahead assertion, thus allowing it to capture the result. What we end up with are empty matches (only matches at the particular locations where 16 digits follow) and the result (our 16 digits) in the capturing group.

Comment: Yay -- thank you, thank you :)

Comment: Nice, a little simpler than my answer (in a good way!).

Answer (score 5):

As ctwheels alluded to in his/her comment, to get overlapping matches like you want, you need to use a concept called a [lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is an expression that evaluates whether a condition is or is not satisfied without consuming those characters. These are called positive and negative lookahead assertions, respectively. Consider the following expression:

```
\d(?=(\d{15}))
```

The first `\d` will match a single digit and consume that character in the expression. This is followed by a positive lookahead assertion (denoted by `(?=expression)`) that tests whether that single digit is followed by another 15 digits, without consuming those 15 characters. Not consuming those characters means that the expression can find additional matches starting with the first character *after* the one matched by the initial `\d`. So:

```
var expression = @"\d(?=(\d{15}))";
var testString = "564654564553314342340968580654";

var regex = new Regex(expression);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(testString))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[0].Value}{match.Groups[1].Value}");
}
```

In my `Console.WriteLine` I am aggregating the contents of the two groups that will appear in each match: the first being the leading digit and the second being the group of 15 digits that follows it. The output of the above code is:

```
5646545645533143
6465456455331434
4654564553314342
6545645533143423
5456455331434234
4564553314342340
5645533143423409
6455331434234096
4553314342340968
5533143423409685
5331434234096858
3314342340968580
3143423409685806
1434234096858065
4342340968580654
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation!!!

Comment: I'm leaving the answer here since the text might be useful, but the expression in @ctwheels' answer is better; I didn't realize you could put the entire thing into the assertion. So I learned something too! Thanks, ctwheels!

Comment: Your explanation definitely complements my answer too so +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a approach without RegEx

```
// test with a 29 digit number
string input = "564654564553314342340968580654";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 16+1; i++)
{
    string result = string.Concat(input.Skip(i).Take(16));
    if (result.All(x => char.IsDigit(x)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/igGMSL

Comment: Thank you but I need many matches -- the first 16 digits starting with the first number, the 16 digits starting with the second number, etc.